# Option breakeven

Tags: call-options

If a 50 call is sold for a $4 premium (exclude commission for this illustration), the buyer's breakeven on the trade is 54 (i.e. 50+4). Correct? As the seller of that call, is it correct to calculate the probability of the underlying security reaching 54, rather than 50, before a buyer exercises for a profit? If the party exercising the option is different from the original buyer, does the different party still have the same $54 breakeven? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The decision to exercise is based on the strike, not breakeven. If you buy an 50 call for $4, your breakeven is $54 because at $54 you'd make a $4 profit from the option (assuming you immediately sold the stock for $54), offsetting the $4 premium you paid. But even if the stock was at $52, you'd *still* exercise the option - you profit from the option would be only $2 and you'd have a net loss of $2, which is better than *not* exercising and having a loss of $4.

The same is true for the seller - it's just a bit easier to visualize as the buyer since the buyer has the optionality. If you sell a 50 call for $4 and the underlying is at $52, they would exercise the option and you'd lose $2 from the option (i.e. you bought the stock at $52 to cover the short call and sold it for $50) for a net profit of $2.

So it's proper to calculate the probability of the stock going to the *strike* rather then the *breakeven* since the cutoff point for exercising the option is the strike, not the breakeven price.

> If the party exercising the option is different from the original buyer, does the different party still have the same $54 breakeven?

If the option is sold and re-bought by a different buyer who pays a different price, yes they would have a different breakeven that you, but that would still not change the probability of *exercise* only the *net profit*  that the other buyer would get at expiry.

The other party's breakeven is pretty much irrelevant to you.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation was really informative. Forgive my continuing confusion. But If the underlying reached, say 52, would the buyer more likely sell to close (i.e. the buy option would increase by $2) rather than exercise. If so, would that closing by buyer have no effect on the seller's trade, thus increasing the likelihood of expiring the sell trade as worthless, and keeping the entire premium?

Comment: If they sell to close, then they sell it to someone else, who might also sell to close or keep it until expiry. The bottom line is that the option will _eventually_ settle somewhere. There's no way that you can keep a short ITM option that will not be exercised by someone.  _You_ can buy to close, but you would have to pay the current market price.  The only way that you would "keep the whole premium" is if the stock was above the strike for a put (or below the strike for a call)